# How to parse input stream using net.sf.json library

Tags: json

Following is the response in Json i am getting after making get request to Http API Format,

```
[{"name":"test","tracing":false},{"name":"dyn1","tracing":false},
{"name":"dyn2","tracing":false},{"name":"esb","tracing":false}]
```

Could you please post a sample code to parse this json object to get individual Host object with name and tracing.

Thanks,

Amol

Answer (score 1):

```
String myDataAsAString = "[{\"name\":\"test\",\"tracing\":false},{\"name\":\"dyn1\",\"tracing\":false},
{\"name\":\"dyn2\",\"tracing\":false},{\"name\":\"esb\",\"tracing\":false}]";


JSONArray hostArray = JSONArray.fromObject(myDataAsAString);

for(int i = 0; i < hostArray.size(); i++)
{
    JSONObject hostObject = hostArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String hostName = hostObject.getString("name");
    boolean tracing = hostObject.getBoolean("tracing");
    ...your code for each element here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can yse GSON library http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Try:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    String json = "[{'name':'test','tracing':false},{'name':'dyn1','tracing':false},\n" +
            "{'name':'dyn2','tracing':false},{'name':'esb','tracing':false}]";
    HostObj[] hostObjects = new Gson().fromJson(json, HostObj[].class);
  }


  class HostObj {

    private String name;
    private boolean tracing;

    HostObj() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        name = name;
    }

    public boolean isTracing() {
        return tracing;
    }

    public void setTracing(boolean tracing) {
        tracing = tracing;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: lol, he's asking for a specific library and you post a different one ;)